# What's the most efficient way to create routes on google maps from gps files?

Tags: google-maps, gps, google-maps-api-3

I want to display my bicycle routes on Google maps. All the coordinates are recorded by my GPS and stored in .gpx file format.

I'd like to know what's the best approach/file formats/storage/loading the coordinates on Google Maps.

This is a good [example](http://home.mindspring.com/~mfkenney/gpstracks.html) but it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 6):

You may be interested in checking out the following article, fresh from the Google Geo Developers Blog:

- [Map your data with the Maps API and Fusion Tables](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2010/05/map-your-data-with-maps-api-and-fusion.html)

Quoting the introduction:

> If you have ever tried to plot a very large number of overlays on an API map you have probably reached a point at which the performance of your application begins to suffer. With one hundred or so markers, most browsers cope just fine, and clustering solutions like [Fluster](http://www.google.com/url?q=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.fusonic.net%2Farchives%2Ftag%2Ffluster&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNElY4AMubOXzKoGotPRFwqmNfL3Jw) can help support more. But if you have thousands of overlays that you wish to show, rendering them individually can be problematic.
>
> The Maps API v3 now offers two solutions to this problem. If you have a large volume of geospatial data that can be served as KML, the [KmlLayer](http://www.google.com/url?q=http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#KMLLayers) class can render up to 50,000 features as an overlay that does not impact performance on any browser. To support data sets that are structured as tables, such as a database or spreadsheet, we have also now added the [FusionTablesLayer](http://www.google.com/url?q=http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#FusionTablesLayer) class for rendering data stored in Google Fusion Tables.

They have a very interesting example visualizing mountain bike trails uploaded to Fusion Tables.

Comment: Fusion table data for MTB trails: https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?dsrcid=132848.  Standalone map: http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/fusiontables/cycletrails.html