# how to load markers if their location is what is displayed on screen using Google maps api or gmaps.js

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, maps, google-maps-markers, area

i have a bunch of markers that i want to add to a map dynamically.

I am getting this markers from a database as a json object and placing them on the map, when the map loads

The map i have is in a div `300px x 300px`.

The issue i'm trying to solve  is that i only want to load the markers that are on the visible part of the map.

I know the `lat` and `long` of each marker so the question is how do i find the area that is displayed on the screen, and maybe the `lat` and `long` ranges.

If i pan the map i want the are to update so i can show more markers...

not sure if this makes sense :)

any ideas on this issue ?

Comment: See this related question [Google Maps V3: Only show markers in viewport](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943474/google-maps-v3-only-show-markers-in-viewport-clear-markers-issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

observe the `bounds_changed`-event of the map. When it fires , you may use the `contains`-method of the `bounds` of the map(returned by `mapInstance.getBounds()` ) to filter the markers .